# Prove, that $F_B := \{B\cap A: A \in F\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $F = \sigma(\Omega)$ and $B \subset \Omega$.
>
> Prove that $F_B := \{B\cap A: A \in F\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$.

Okay, so I have three conditions to check:

1. $B \in F_B$
2. $c \in F_B \Rightarrow B\setminus x\in F_B$
3. $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i \in F_B$

**Ad.1** I know that $\Omega \subset F$ and $B \subset \Omega$. I wish I could claim at this point that $B \in F_B$ but it doesn't seem that obvious to me.

**Ad.2** $\forall_{ c \in F_B} \ \exists_{A\in F} \ c = A\cap B$  but what's next?

**Ad.3** $C_1, C_2, ... \in F_B$

$\bigcup C_i = \bigcup A_i\cap B = (\bigcup A_i)\cap B$ and again... what's the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B=B\cap \Omega$ and $\Omega \in F$ so $B \in F_B$.

Let $E \in F_B$. then there exists $A \in F$ such that $E=A\cap B$. Now the complement of $E$ in $B$ is $B\setminus E=B\cap A^{c}$ and $A^{c} \in F$ so $E^{c} \in F_B$.

Let $E_i \in F_B, =1,2,...$. There exist $A_1,A_2,... \in F$ such that $E_i=B\cap A_i$ for all $i$. Since $\bigcup_i E_i=\bigcup_i A_i \cap B$ and $\bigcup_i A_i \in F$ we see that $\bigcup_i E_i \in F_B$.

Comment: Ok, so in the first line we simply take $A = \Omega$?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @FilipWichrowski