# Prove that $A_B=\left\{B \cap A \,; A \in \mathbb{A} \right\}$ is a σ-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I found the following statement and I don't see exactly why it's true so if any of you guys could help , thanks in advance.

So we have $(E,\mathbb{A}) \;$ a measurable space  and $B \subset E $

and define the injective function $\gamma :$

> $$\gamma : (B,A_B) \rightarrow (E,\mathbb{A})$$
>   $$x \mapsto x $$

Then :

> i) $A_B=\left\{B \cap A \,; A \in \mathbb{A} \right\}$ is a σ-algebra on B 
>    that makes the injection $\gamma\,$  measurable .
>
> ii) If $B\in \mathbb{A}$ , we have $A_B =\left\{ A \in \mathbb{A}\,;\,A\subset B \right\}.$

Also I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442078/prove-that-f-b-b-cap-a-a-in-f-is-a-sigma-algebra-on-b) something that might help for i) but I don't see how it makes $\gamma$ measurable  , but still have no clue for ii)

Comment: $\gamma$ is measurable because for each $A\in\mathbb A$, either $A\in A_B$ in which case $\gamma^{-1}(A)=A\in A_B$, or $A\notin A_B$, in which case $\gamma^{-1}(A) = \varnothing\in A_B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gamma$ is measurable because for each $A\in\mathbb A$, either $A\in A_B$ in which case $\gamma^{-1}(A)=A\in A_B$, or $A\notin A_B$, in which case $\gamma^{-1}(A) = \varnothing\in A_B$.

Let $A^B = \{A\in\mathcal A:A\subset B\}$. If $C\in A_B$ then $C=B\cap A$ for some $A\in\mathbb A$, so $C\in\mathbb A$ and $C\subset B$ so that $C\in A^B$. Similarly, if $C\in A^B$ then $C\in\mathbb A$ and $C\subset B$, so $C = B\cap C\in A_B$. It follows that $A^B=A_B$.